# Win32: Combobox loses focus when clicking its child window

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox

I have a c++ Win32 application with a node-based GUI where I create a dynamic combobox with CreateWindowEx when the user presses a certain key within the GUI. I want the user to be able to click outside of the combobox Rect in order to make the combobox disappear.

To do this, I'm currently destroying the combobox inside a WM_KILLFOCUS notification of its DlgProc (so any click outside of it destroys it). However, it seems that the WM_KILLFOCUS notification is sent anytime one of its child windows gains focus. For example, if I click in the combobox's edit text region, the combobox itself loses focus since that child gains focus. Given my setup, this causes the combobox to be removed when clicking within it's Rect.

How can I prevent this behavior? Basically I want to be able to detect when anything other than the combobox or its child windows gains focus, rather than simply detecting if the combobox itself loses focus.

Comment: You should add a picture to your question. It's a bit hard to understand what you really want. What do you mean by "removing the combobox"? Removing the drop down part of the combobox or remove the whole combobox control? Normally you don't need to do anything special for comboboxes, they just "work" out of the box.

Comment: I edited the post. By remove I mean destroy the entire combobox HWND with a call to DestroyWindow.

Comment: I think using WM_KILLFOCUS is not the correct methode here.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine, whether focus moves to a different control from inside the [WM_KILLFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/wm-killfocus) handler. This message receives

> [a] handle to the window that receives the keyboard focus.

through its *wParam* argument.

Use the [CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message to retrieve a [COMBOBOXINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) structure, that contains window handles to all contributing windows (*hwndCombo*, *hwndItem*, and *hwndList*). Comparing the *wParam* value to all of those window handles allows you to determine, whether focus moves inside the combo box or outside.

---

While this answers the question that was asked, the real solution would be to handle the [CBN_KILLFOCUS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/cbn-killfocus) notification instead. It is sent to the control parent when the combo box loses keyboard focus, ignoring focus change events internal to the combo box control.

Comment: This would introduce an subsequent issue. Once the focus is within the edit box within the  combo box, the combo box HWND itself won't get the `WM_KILLFOCUS` if the focus moves to a location outside the combobox. Sounds like OP would need to subclass the combo box constituent windows in order to track focus leaving the entire set of windows.